# How to add and sort specific rows of textline?

Tags: linux, perl, awk

I have 2 files:

- first.txt
- second.txt

first.txt contain:

```
A
B
C
D
A
B
C
D
```

second.txt contain:

```
1 header
123
456
2 header
123
1 header
123
2 header
123
456
```

> How to add and sort every 1 header 123 to 2 header 123 of second.txt into every
>   ABCD of first.txt like below:

```
A
B
C
D
1 header
123
456
2 header
123
A
B
C
D
1 header
123
2 header
123
456
```

I tried using `cat first.txt second.txt`, but it only output like below:

```
A
B
C
D
A
B
C
D
1 header
123
456
2 header
123
1 header
123
2 header
123
456
```

Do you guys have any ideas?
These are sample problem, the real problem have million rows of textline, due to sensitive dataset I can only share sample problem only.

Thanks,
Am

Comment: is `A B C D` always on 4 lines?

Comment: Yep, A B C D is always on 4 lines.

Comment: So your first file contains N=4*n lines (where n is an integer) with a repetition of the first 4th lines all over the file?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you please try following and let me know if this helps you.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{
  if(FNR%4==0 && FNR>1){
     a[++i]=val ORS $0;
     val="";
     next};
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0;
  next
}
count==3{
  print a[++j] ORS val;
  count="";
  val=""}
/header/{
  count++}
{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0
}
END{
  if(count){
    print a[++j] ORS val}
}' first.txt second.txt
```

Output will be as follows.

```
A
B
C
D
1 header
123
456
2 header
123
A
B
C
D
1 header
123
2 header
123
456
```

***Explanation:*** Adding explanation of above code too now.

```
awk '
FNR==NR{                 ##Checking condition if FNR value is eqaul to NR value which will be TRUE when first Input_file is being read.
  if(FNR%4==0 && FNR>1){ ##Checking condition if line is completly divided by 4 and NOT the first line then do following.
     a[++i]=val ORS $0;  ##Creating an array named a whose index is variable i increasing value and value is variable val value along with new line and current line.
     val="";             ##Nullifying the variable val here.
     next};              ##Using next keyword to skip al next statements here.
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0; ##Creating variable named val whose value is concatenating its own value in it.
  next                   ##Using next keyword to skip all further statements from here now.
}
count==3{                ##Checking condition if variable named count is 3 then do following.
  print a[++j] ORS val;  ##Printing value of array a whose index is variable j with increasing value of 1 in it then ORS and value of variable val here.
  count="";              ##Nullifying the variable count here.
  val=""}                ##Nullifying the variable val here now.
/header/{                ##Checking condition if a line is having string header in it then do following.
  count++}               ##Increasing the value of variable count with 1 here.
{
  val=val?val ORS $0:$0  ##Creating variable named val whose value is concatenating its own values.
}
END{                     ##Starting END section here of awk.
  if(count){             ##Checking condition if variable count value is NOT NULL then do following.
    print a[++j] ORS val}##Printing value of array a whose index is variable j and ORS and then value of variable val here.
}' first.txt second.txt  ##Mentioning Input_file(s) named first.txt and second.txt here.
```

Comment: Hi Ravinder, thanks for answering my question. I will try your sample code and will let you know if it good.

Comment: Hi Ravin, could you explain a little bit on your code? Thanks.

Comment: This script works very well on both sample and my assignment. I just need to edit the /header/, count==3 and FNR%4==0 && FNR>1 on my assignment. Thank you very much for sharing your ideas.

Comment: @Amz, added explanation to my code now too, please do let me know in case of any queries on same.

Comment: DOWN VOTER: This is not fair, without giving reason down votes, this is 2nd for the day for me.

Comment: Great explanation. I don't  know whom downvote it. Anyway, thanks again Ravin.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13: Let me up vote it! I am also getting pissed off with all those down vote who do not leave a feedback... As usual great answer! Buddy!

Comment: @Allan, thanks buddy it really discourages when someone down votes without any reasons :(

Answer (score 1):

Then it will be quite straightforwards:

```
BUFF=`sed -n '1,4p' first.txt`; awk -v buff="$BUFF" '!/^1 header$/{print}/^1 header$/{print buff;print}' second.txt
A
B
C
D
1 header
123
456
2 header
123
A
B
C
D
1 header
123
2 header
123
456
```

You store in a variable the 4th lines using `sed -n '1,4p'`. Then you pass that variable content to `awk` by using the syntax `-v buff="$BUFF"`. The core of the `sed` program will read the second file and for each line that does not contain exactly `1 header` your print the line, when you reach a line whose content is `1 header` then you print the 4 lines extracted with your `sed` command before printing that specific line.

Comment: Hi Allan, thanks for answering my question. I will try your sample code first, and will let you know if it is good.

Comment: Your script works very well on my sample, but it didn't work on my real assignment. Anyway it is good for my future reference as it gave me an idea to solve another problem. Thanks Allan.